# What is the difference between a list of a single iterable `list(x)` vs `[x]`?

Tags: python, list

Python seems to differentiate between `[x]` and `list(x)` when making a list object, where `x` is an iterable. Why this difference?

```
>>> a = [dict(a=1)]
>>> a
[{'a': 1}]

>>> a = list(dict(a=1))
>>> a
['a']
```

While the 1st expression seems to work as expected, the 2nd expression works more like iterating a dict this way:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for e in {'a': 1}:
...     l.append(e)
>>> l
['a']
```

Comment: `[] == list()` might give you the impression that `list()` is like e.g. `array()` in PHP – just an alternate syntax – but that’s not the case. It’s a type that gives an empty list when called with no arguments, converts an iterable to a list when called with one argument, and can’t be called with more than one argument. `[x]` is not equivalent to `list(x)`, and `list(x, y, …)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[x]` is a list containing the **element** `x`.

`list(x)` takes `x` (which must already be **iterable**!) and turns it into a list.

```
>>> [1]  # list literal
[1]
>>> ['abc']  # list containing 'abc'
['abc']
>>> list(1)
# TypeError
>>> list((1,))  # list constructor
[1]
>>> list('abc')  # strings are iterables
['a', 'b', 'c']  # turns string into list!
```

The list constructor `list(...)` - like all of python's built-in collection types (set, list, tuple, collections.deque, etc.) - can take a single iterable argument and convert it.