# First dictionary element of a set is mysteriously turned into an integer

Tags: python, set

I am trying to write an hashable dictionary:

```
class HashableDict(dict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(frozenset(self.items()))
```

However, this leads to an unexpected behaviour. If I create a set like this:

```
x = HashableDict({0: 1})
y = HashableDict({0: 2})
print(set((x, y)))
```

This, as expected, prints `{{0: 1}, {0: 2}}`. However, if I create the following set:

```
x = HashableDict({0: 1})
print(set(x))
```

Python3.9 prints `{0}`. This does not happen if I use `{x}` instead (i.e., `{0: 1}` is printed). To add to the mystery, the following code:

```
A = set(x)
A.add(y)
print(A)
```

Prints `{0, {0: 2}}`. So this only happens for the first element of the set...

What am I doing wrong? Note that I also tried adding a `__eq__` method that works consistently with `__hash__`, but this does not solve it:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return frozenset(self.items()) == frozenset(other.items())
```

Answer (score 2):

The set constructor takes an iterable as argument and creates a set of all the iterable's elements. Since iterating a `dict` only iterates the keys, you get a set of its keys:

```
set(x) # takes x and turns it into a set!
```

You, however, want a `set` **containing** `x`:

```
set([x])  # takes a list containing x and turns it into a set
# {x}  # is the equivalent
```

Note that `{x}` and `set(x)` are **not** the same, reagardless of the type of x!

Also see [What is the difference between a list of a single iterable `list(x)` vs `[x]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999726/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-of-a-single-iterable-listx-vs-x)
and many other duplicates concerned with this *"collection literal vs. constructor"*.